How can I keep Google Colab from disconnecting in 2024?
I'm having problem running Google Colab, I need it to run around 12-15 hours for model training but it keeps disconnecting after 6-8 hours.
I've used these two snippets from this thread:  How can I prevent Google Colab from disconnecting?
function ClickConnect(){
  colab.config
  console.log("Connnect Clicked - Start"); 
  document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
  console.log("Connnect Clicked - End");
};
setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000)

function ClickRefresh(){
  console.log("Working"); 
  document.querySelector("[icon='colab:folder-refresh']").click()
}
const myjob = setInterval(ClickRefresh, 60000)

to try and keep Colab running
But they do not work.
I've had restart the training three times, and I only have 68 compute units left.

This question is similar to: How can I prevent Google Colab from disconnecting?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Can not keep Google Colab running in the Free version.
However, you can save and load model_state_dict to continue your training process. Furthermore, if you have multiple google accounts, you might be able to switch between them for continuously training.
Here is the pytorch formal sample notebook.
You could do the trick by torch.save() and torch.load()
Save:
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)

Load:
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH), weights_only=True)


As far as I know, you cannot keep Google Colab running in the free version. I have no information about the paid version. Additionally, I searched the internet and found that as of March 2021, it is not possible to keep Google Colab running.

Yea ... Google is a business, not a charity.

I got gcolab pro+ but even tho it apparently allows background execution up to 12 hours it still keeps disconnecting.
